# asp.net webform allow access for only certain ip

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

We have an existing asp.net webform (.net 4) application runnning in production.  Recently the users have requested a new page be built, but that page they want only accessible through 1 ip address.  Can someone guide me on how to do this?  I've seen online ip restrictions at the IIS level, but I don't want to restrict the entire application as it should remain open to all, just that one page should be restricted.

Getting the users' ip I saw I can use the sample from 
[How to get a user's client IP address in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net)

But is the only way then to restrict it to do a test if returnedIP == "xx.xxx.x.x" or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Just in case you think the duplicate is not appropriate, you can tune access rights at the folder level, not only at the application or site level.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi so if i drop the new page into a subfolder, i can restrict that folder's access to 1 ip in IIS, but the rest of the site can remain open?

Comment: Absolutely. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/431027/464709) in the duplicate elaborates on that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi will talk to our network group and see if they can set it up this way.